# Нестандартная вёрстка, css "прилепить" к низу родительского

Tags: html, css

```css
body
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%!important;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  color: #444;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#contents
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 200px;
  right: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #0ff;
  border: 0px solid #ff0000;
}

#contentframe
{
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#lmenu
{
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  min-width: 200px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #6495ed;
}

#mapframe
{
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  min-height: 400px;
  background-color: #000;
}

#btmenu
{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #ff0;
  border: 0px solid #0000ff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylize/main_style.css">
    <title>tester</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="lmenu">
    left menu
  </div>
  <div id="contents">
    <div id="mapframe"></div>
      <div id="contentframe">
      <h3>Преимущества</h3>
      <ul><li>
          <p><b>Покрытие.</b> <a href="http://maps.yandex.ru/?index">Сотни подробных схем</a> городов России, Украины, Казахстана и Беларуси. Если официальная схема города недостаточно полная, используйте <a href="/maps/features/?p=nmaps">Народную карту</a>, которую рисуют сами пользователи по спутниковым снимкам. </p>
        </li><li>
          <p><b>Дополнительная информация</b>. Можно показать на карте автомобильные <a href="/maps/features/?p=traffic">пробки и дорожные события</a>. Или автоматически строить <a href="/maps/features/?p=routing">маршруты</a> в России и Украине.</p>
        </li><li>
          <p><b>Управление</b>. Управлять информацией на карте несложно.  Контент-менеджер сможет заносить данные на сайт в виде текста,  поскольку сервис <a href="/maps/features/?p=geocode">геокодирования</a> преобразует адрес в метку на карте автоматически. Также существует и обратный вариант — можно узнать адрес метки, просто кликнув в нужное место карты.</p>
        </li><li>
          <p><b>Нагрузка.</b> Яндекс.Карты рассчитаны на миллионы пользователей, поэтому карта на вашем сайте выдержит любую нагрузку. Если вам нужно разместить на карте множество точек, вы можете их <a href="/maps/features/?p=cluster">сгруппировать</a> или использовать <a href="/maps/features/?p=hotspot">специальные технологии</a>, чтобы не снижать производительность. </p>
        </li><li>
          <p><b>Индивидуальный дизайн.</b> API Яндекс.Карт позволяет по своему усмотрению изменять внешний вид меток, всплывающих подсказок (балунов), линий и элементов управления. Также вы можете использовать расширенную библиотеку стандартных меток.</p>
        </li><li>
          <p><b>Поддержка мобильных устройств.</b>
            С помощью Яндекс.Карт можно <a href="/maps/features/?p=mobile">дополнить мобильную версию сайта</a>. Карты подойдут для большинства мобильных устройств.</p>
        </li><li>
          <p><b>Безопасность.</b>
            Информация, размещаемая на картах, сохраняется на сайте и не передается вовне (в том числе в Яндекс). Всё, что вы хотите показать на картах, останется вашим собственным контентом. А если ваш сайт работает по защищенному протоколу, вы можете подключиться к API Яндекс.Карт по <a href="/maps/features/?p=https">HTTPS</a>. </p>
        </li></ul>
        <div id="btmenu">bottom menu</div>
      </div>
      </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Нужно "прилепить" `#btmenu` к низу `#contentframe`. Никак не получается.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
body
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%!important;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  color: #444;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#contents
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 200px;
  right: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #0ff;
  border: 0px solid #ff0000;
}

#contentframe
{
  position: relative;
}

#lmenu
{
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  min-width: 200px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #6495ed;
}

#mapframe
{
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  min-height: 400px;
  background-color: #000;
}

#btmenu
{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left:0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #ff0;
  border: 0px solid #0000ff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylize/main_style.css">
    <title>tester</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="lmenu">
    left menu
  </div>
  <div id="contents">
    <div id="mapframe"></div>
      <div id="contentframe">
      <h3>Преимущества</h3>
      <ul><li>
          <p><b>Покрытие.</b> <a href="http://maps.yandex.ru/?index">Сотни подробных схем</a> городов России, Украины, Казахстана и Беларуси. Если официальная схема города недостаточно полная, используйте <a href="/maps/features/?p=nmaps">Народную карту</a>, которую рисуют сами пользователи по спутниковым снимкам. </p>
        </li><li>
          <p><b>Дополнительная информация</b>. Можно показать на карте автомобильные <a href="/maps/features/?p=traffic">пробки и дорожные события</a>. Или автоматически строить <a href="/maps/features/?p=routing">маршруты</a> в России и Украине.</p>
        </li><li>
          <p><b>Управление</b>. Управлять информацией на карте несложно.  Контент-менеджер сможет заносить данные на сайт в виде текста,  поскольку сервис <a href="/maps/features/?p=geocode">геокодирования</a> преобразует адрес в метку на карте автоматически. Также существует и обратный вариант — можно узнать адрес метки, просто кликнув в нужное место карты.</p>
        </li><li>
          <p><b>Нагрузка.</b> Яндекс.Карты рассчитаны на миллионы пользователей, поэтому карта на вашем сайте выдержит любую нагрузку. Если вам нужно разместить на карте множество точек, вы можете их <a href="/maps/features/?p=cluster">сгруппировать</a> или использовать <a href="/maps/features/?p=hotspot">специальные технологии</a>, чтобы не снижать производительность. </p>
        </li><li>
          <p><b>Индивидуальный дизайн.</b> API Яндекс.Карт позволяет по своему усмотрению изменять внешний вид меток, всплывающих подсказок (балунов), линий и элементов управления. Также вы можете использовать расширенную библиотеку стандартных меток.</p>
        </li><li>
          <p><b>Поддержка мобильных устройств.</b>
            С помощью Яндекс.Карт можно <a href="/maps/features/?p=mobile">дополнить мобильную версию сайта</a>. Карты подойдут для большинства мобильных устройств.</p>
        </li><li>
          <p><b>Безопасность.</b>
            Информация, размещаемая на картах, сохраняется на сайте и не передается вовне (в том числе в Яндекс). Всё, что вы хотите показать на картах, останется вашим собственным контентом. А если ваш сайт работает по защищенному протоколу, вы можете подключиться к API Яндекс.Карт по <a href="/maps/features/?p=https">HTTPS</a>. </p>
        </li></ul>
        <div id="btmenu">bottom menu</div>
      </div>
      </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавляем к **#contentfram**

```
position: relative;
```

а к **#btmenu**

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left:0;
```

Comment: Ошибся. Не к #contentframe, а к #content. Сейчас он absolute. Если его сделать relative - правый край уедет на ширину #lmenu вправо.